# Python/Pandas - ValueError: Shape of passed values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use `pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)` to concatenate a list of data frames however I am getting the following error message `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (35, 79), indices imply (35, 73)`.

I don't understand why this is as each of the data frames have the same shape - (73, 7) - so to me they should concatenate without an issue?

Comment: Maybe the best test shapes .. `for df in df_list: print (df.shape)`

Comment: Thanks but I had already checked this, as per op the shape of every df in the list is (73, 7)

Comment: That's really weird! Is it possible that your frames have duplicates in the row index? Could you check what happens, if you do an explicit `df= df.reset_index()` on the dataframe in your loop before you `concat` them. Does that change something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to add the two dataframe columnwise? so you get a dataframe with 70 columns? or do you want to concatenate them rowwise?

If you want to add them rowwise, just change your axis-parameter:

```
pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

You can also use the more verbose strings `'index'` instead of 0 and `'columns'` instead of 1.

If you have generic indexes, you might also need option `ingore_index=True` because otherwise you might get duplicate entries in the result index.

Comment: Thanks, yes I do want to do them column-wise. I have also tried `ingore_index=True` but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

if you have two pandas data,data1 and data2,that want to concat them in column .you should do this and it solve the problem.

```
    data1=data1.values
    data1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
    data2=data2.values
    data2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
    data=pd.concat([data1,data2],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```